# What animal would be the most likely to become human-like after an asteroid wipes out all mammals?

Tags: extinction

If an asteroid struck the Earth with enough power to cause the extinction of mammalian life, which animal would be the most likely to both survive the event, and evolve to be able to use language and invent complex tools? The mammalian extinction does not need to be complete, it just has to end the reign of mammals, in the same way that the K-Pg extinction event ended the reign of dinosaurs

Comment: There's no factual way to answer this; it can only be opinion based.  VTC.

Comment: A long long time ago, I read in a kid science book that mice and octopuses were good candidates to develop organized societies and build complex things. Note however it was from a book aimed at young audiences. I don't have enough evidence to say it's what scientists think seriously, or if it was only to give a little bit of childream powered fuel!

Comment: @ZeissIkon How is it opinion-based?

Comment: Because there is literally no way to predict this.  There isn't a non-mammalian family of animals that we can look at and say, "Hey, these guys have the potential to develop language and technology a few million years after we're gone."  Biology doesn't work like that.

Comment: @ZeissIkon There are definitely some things we can predict: For example, it certainly won't be an echinoderm or plant, but corvids, if they could survive, would almost certainly take our place

Comment: Sure, *could* -- so could octopodes, if they can overcome being acquatic.  But evolution raises surprises.  Who'd have predicted that the ceolacanth would still be around 100 million years after it left a fossil record (and then didn't)?  Who'd have known that Notharctis was destined to produce the great apes and hominids and eventually the hominins?

Comment: @ZeissIkon To look at your examples, it would be incredibly obvious that the coelacanth wouln't evolve into great apes or anything else terrestrial, while there were still other animals on the Earth. Even if it can't be predicted perfectly, it can still be predicted well enough

Comment: *"In the same way that the K-Pg extinction event ended the reign of dinosaurs":* There are many more extant species of dinosaurus than of mammals, and very many more dinosaurian individuals alive than mammalian, humans included. (Counting living individuals, dinosaurs outnumber mammals anywhere between 5 and 40 to 1 -- we don't know because nobody can count their uncountable multitude.)

Comment: @AlexP Birds do not have the same diversity of forms as either mammals or non-avian dinosaurs

Comment: I'll concede that extant maniraptorans are less diverse than non-avian dinosaurs; but their diversity is quite comparable with than of mammals. Mammals have the cetaceans as outliers, birds have the ratites (and penguins!) as outliers. There isn't more difference between a tiny shrew and a lion than between a hummingbird and an eagle.

Comment: "with enough power to cause the extinction of mammalian life" That alone might be the basis of a good question - what other life could possibly even survive after an impact that could wipe out all mammalian species. I have a feeling a lot of non-mammals would be in trouble in such a scenario.

Comment: I was half tempted to not close this Q, but as I thought about it, how can you judge what "most likely" really is? The dinosaurs weren't sapient, but humanity is - and something that can kill a sapient species is a *whole lot worse* than what killed the dinos. After that, anything, literally anything, could rise to the top given enough time and the right circumstances. We could list the pros and cons of individual species... but which one even *might* win out is an unadulterated guess. So... VTC.

Comment: It is pure opinion but the author may not realize it is pure opinion, predicting evolution that far out is heavy speculation, adding in surviving a mass extinction which is also heavy speculation leaves you with so little confidence it is little better than a random guess, you could have a thousand answers for a thousand different animals all equally likely, which counts as opinion based for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a major extinction event, evolution tends to explode in some survivor group/s, to fill the void. You get [huge and wild diversification in a very very short time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_radiation). After the dinosaurs, shrew-like mammals quickly evolved into everything mammal, including for example bats and whales.

As a result, nobody can tell. If mammals vanish in a  similar event, evolution is going to go **wild** for a while, and the life forms that arise will be virtually unpredictable. After all, if I showed you a shrew, could you predict a whale? Or a rhino?

And even before that, you'd have to guess which kinds of animals the unpredictable evolutionary explosion starts from......

Answer (score 1):

#### **Rats, squirrels, corvids, or parrots**

It's impossible to predict precisely which way evolution will go, and sapience is far from a guaranteed path. Nevertheless, there are some animals that are very unlikely to evolve sapience (e.g., koalas), and others which are more likely. Again, this isn't accounting for things like potential adaptive radiation to fill unexpected, unoccupied niches (if you surveyed dinosaurs before the K.T. they would have probably argued notosuchians would have taken their place), but this is based from the trends we can see.

Notably, the four most likely groups to evolve into sapient tool-users are rats, squirrels, corvids, and parrots, for various reasons. Rats and corvids are highly adaptable omnivores, do well in degraded or destabilized environments like a highly urbanized city or a post-extinction environment, are fairly social, and are good problem-solvers and/or use tools. Tool use is certain crows is well known, but Norway rats (*Rattus norvegicus*) [can also be trained to use tools to solve problems in a similar fashion](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0226569).

Squirrels are a potential runner up, squirrels in general (except burrowing squirrels like prairie dogs and marmots) have much larger brains relative to their bodies than rats, and their arboreal habits suggest that they might be more easily manipulated into developing primate-like habits that could lead to a convergent evolution with humans as a tool-using social animal. However, most tree squirrels are also highly dependent on nuts and fruits for survival (again, except for marmots, prairie dogs, and some omnivorous squirrels like *Ictidomys*), and an extinction comparable to the K-T could wipe out enough fruiting trees to make their survival doubtful. And again, no guarantee they'll continue to get bigger brains and become more human-like, indeed rodents are ancestrally characterized by a *decrease* in relative brain size compared to other Euarchontoglires. Big brains are not always better.

Parrots are fourth place, there are a lot of them (~350), they're intelligent, but the downside is they're even more dependent on fruit than squirrels are (only a handful of species like the kea, kakapo, or the Antipodes parakeet [*Cyanorhamphus unicolor*] aren't specialized frugivores).

As for other intelligent animals...
**Cephalopods**: Probably not, as they're stuck in the water (no fire), lack long-term social structures, and are shackled by very short life spans and semelparous reproduction. The usual selective benefit of sapience is passing on survival knowledge to new generations, and cephalopods...can't.
**Cetaceans**: Also stuck in the water. Lack any means of manipulation (their flippers are only mobile at the shoulder joint). Large size means they would die out just like the marine reptiles of the Cretaceous did.
**Canids**: Forearms are very specialized for locomotion and lack thumbs, bad choice for tool users even compared to other mammals.
**Pigs**: Lack manipulatory organs. Nothing larger than a cat survived the K-T on land, pigs likely wouldn't either.
**Elephants**: Elephant have trouble outliving humans *now*, let alone in an extinction scenario.
**Primates**: Except for humans and some baboons are mostly forest-dwelling and fruit dependent. Too large to reliably survive.

Also, a big, big difference between the K-T and what you're asking is that mammals wouldn't respond to such an extinction the same way that dinosaurs did. Namely, during the Mesozoic dinosaurs were mostly kept out of small-sized niches by mammals and crocodylians (except in arboreal and aerial habitats, which is where small theropods evolved into birds), and the dinosaur method of reproduction systematically favored large species and disfavored small ones due to dinosaurs occupying multiple ecological niches as they aged. Thus, a big mass extinction would disproportionately affect dinosaurs much more than mammals, as there were and are many small mammals around.

Most likely you'd end up with shrews and rodents reclaiming all the old niches mammals lost, unless you hit the Earth really hard with a P-T or above level extinction...though even then, during the P-T when protomammals were dominant dicynodonts, therocephalians, and cynodonts still survived, even if the results of the extinction lead to the long-term demise of the therocephalians and canalized the dicynodonts into a narrow subset of herbivorous niches (Kannemeyeriiformes) that constrained their ability to adapt and eventually killed them. To completely crush mammals like what happened to the non-avian dinosaurs would require an extinction that would put the survival of life on Earth in doubt, and even then it might be iffy because there really isn't any group that can compete with mammals in their own arena like how the archosaurs could in the Triassic (since birds are constrained from many niches mammals occupy and vice versa).

Comment: almost everything on your list are mammals, the OP specifies the extinction of mammalian life.

Comment: @John Aside from the rats and squirrels, which fit OP's parameters as they say small mammals are allowed so long as general mammalian dominance is broken, the other mammalian taxa (cetaceans, proboscideans, suids, canids, and primates) are explicitly listed as taxa that will *not* survive to give rise to sapient human-like life because they will not survive OP's mammal-destroying mass extinction.

Comment: Corvids, or to be precise the New Caledonian crow, already are not only tool users, but tool _manufacturers_ in the wild. They are the most likely source of sapience in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no way to say, so use whatever you want

Keep in mind whatever takes over after something big enough to wipe out mammals will be complete guesswork and unlikely to be like anything else we know of. You are talking about an extinction event worse than the K-T. It is hard to say what would even survive such an event. Even more importantly it is unlikely whatever it is will resemble its current ancestor in any but the most basic way, crows might be a candidate but they could look more like t-rex by the time it happens. We are not even that sure why humans evolved to be so intelligent.

Predicting extinction and evolution especially of intelligence with any precision that far out is downright impossible. **So you can say your creatures evolved from basically anything** and as long as you have some reasoning no one can really argue.